# Entity without a constraint required

Tags: jpa, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

I have an entity Person with a relation to an other person (mentor). This person can be `null`. I thought just the `Constraints.Required` annotation forces my mentor to be set. 
If I remove the `ManyToOne` annotation the mentor wont be connected.

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Constraints.Required
    public User user;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String firstName;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    public Person mentor;

    ...
```

How can I have a person without a mentor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the `@ManyToOne` annotation is actually "instructing" your JPA provider th think that the `Person` table/relation has a *foreign key* to it (this models the 1:n relation b/n persons to mentors and a foreign key can't be null) but from your question, I see your biz needs doesn't need a 1:n *per se* so simply remove the `@ManyToOne` annotation and on case a person does have a mentor , wire this relation manually in the JPA entity constructor or via setter method

Comment: UNIT-testing, UNIT-testing! Acctualy it can be null. I saw it in a test. The mentors id came back with mentor.id -1. That was the root cause. If I remove the many-to-one it won't be connected with the mentor